# Thickness of complete graph $K_9$

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone help me with this?

I just wanted to clarify the thickness of $K_9$.
The complete graph $K_9$ has 9 vertices and 36 edges. Then,
$t(K_9)=\lceil{\frac{36}{3(9)-6}}\rceil=\lceil{\frac{36}{21}}\rceil=2$ and $t(K_9)=\lfloor{\frac{36+3(9)-7}{3(9)-6}}\rfloor=\lfloor{\frac{56}{21}}\rfloor=2$. But I found out that the thickness of $K_9$ is 3. This is easy to show if $t(K_9)\neq 2$.

How do I prove the thickness of $K_9$?

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you are using $t(K_9)$ to denote the thickness of $K_9$, what do you mean by statements like "$t(K_9)=\lceil{\frac{36}{3(9)-6}}\rceil=\lceil{\frac{36}{21}}\rceil=2$" if the thickness of $K_9$ is $3$ and not $2$?

Answer (score 1):

Your first equation should be  $t(K_9) \geq \lceil(\frac{m}{3(n)-6})\rceil$, it only gives a lower bound.

I'm not sure where your equation which uses the floor function. [The thickness of a complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thickness_(graph_theory)) can be given by $\lfloor \frac{n+7}{6} \rfloor$, except for when $n=9,10$.

[From here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphThickness.html), it can be seen that the minimum number of planar graphs which the edges of $K_9$ can be partitioned into is 3.
[image: k9 thickness]

There is also a more in depth proof for why $K_9$ is non-biplanar and thus the thickness is not $=2$ [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/36A18B25C18B9FF5788D5AE19B2D961D/S0008439500051808a.pdf/nonbiplanar_character_of_the_complete_9graph.pdf).